# PayPal's [txn_id] in IPN and [L_TRANSACTIONID] in TransactionSearch

Tags: paypal

It's a PayPal's problem.
I got `[txn_id]` from IPN.
and I got `[L_TRANSACTIONID]` from TransactionSearch.
They are not same, why?
I want to Compare with them，the listener results and TransactionSearch's result.
How can I get it?

Answer (score 0):

Can you send the details of your issue(include your PayPal account) to PayPal MTS through below site.
https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/app/ask
We will check the your account and give you an answer.

Comment: this should be a comment